# Prove that exists $x_{0} \in ]0,1[$ such that $[f(x_{0})]^2=x_{0}$?.

Tags: calculus, analysis, continuity

Let $f$ $\in C[0,1]$ such that $-1 \leq f(x) \leq 1$ $\forall_{x} \in [0,1]$.Prove that exists $x_{0} \in ]0,1[$  such that $[f(x_{0})]^2=x_{0}$.

I thought I can apply some theorem related to Continuity, be it Bolzano's theorem or the Intermediate Value. But I think it should be done in cases, but I don't know what they would be. Any suggestion or suggestion will be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about $f(x)=0$?

Comment: Isn't this statement false? Consider $f$ identically equal to zero.

Comment: No, it is the statement of the question. :(

Comment: My teacher told me that I could do it in cases, is it possible?

Comment: @TatianaMalespínAlvarado If it is the statement of the question, then the question is wrong, or wrongly copied here (as shown by the example of Brian and Benjamin). Kindly consult your teacher and get back. Maybe $x_0 \in [0,1]$ is allowed? Also, with just the assumptions, I think you are correct in that either Bolzano or Intermediate Value theorem is going to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question as stated here is false as the counterexample $f(x) = 0 $ shows.  In fact there are plenty of other counterexamples with no solution to $f(x)^2 = x$ in the open interval $(0,1)$, such as $f(x) = 1, f(x) = x^n, n>0, \neq \frac{1}{2}$.  However, if the closed interval $[0,1]$ is intended, you can proceed as follows.

Let $g(x) = f(x)^2-x$.  Then, if $g(x)$ is non zero throughout $[0,1]$ the intermediate value theorem implies $g(x)$ cannot change sign n $[0,1]$.  It follows, either $g(x) > 0 $ or $g(x) < 0$ throughout the interval.  In the former case, take $x=1$. It implies $f(1)^2-1>0$ and that contradicts the requirement $-1 \leqslant f(x) \leqslant 1$.  In the latter case, set $x=0$, implying $f(0)^2 < 0$ which is also impossible.  Therefore, by contradiction, $g(x)$ must take the value zero in $[0,1]$ and there is a solution $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)^2=x_0$.